# How to determine I am over fitting my machine learning algorithm and what are other method to evaluate performance of machine learning algorithm?

Tags: deep-learning, roc, overfitting, precision-recall

I am trying to recognize patterns through deep learning. I have data set of 850 images that I split (600 into train and 250 to validation). After I run machine learning algorithm, I get results shown in attached picture. [image: result of my deep learning algorithm run]. How I will know if my model is over fitted or not? Secondly, I want to know what are other ways to evaluate a deep learning model than measuring accuracy and loss? For example can I calculate ROC curve, precision, confusion matrix etc?
Thanks
Umer

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can calculate confusion matrix to visualise your errors in both training and test. The best way to check if your overfitting or not is below:-

1:- Split your dataset in 3 parts, first for training second for validation third for testing.

2:- Train your model so that validation accuracy is increasing in optimal way and set you hyperparameters accordingly like batch size, learning rate, no of hidden layers etc.

3:- After running your training session, test your model on test dataset.

4:- If your test accuracy is somewhat around your training accuracy like let's say your training accuracy is 97.7 % and test accuracy is 93.1%, then it is great.

Remember that there is no rule of thumb to check is our model overfitted or not. You can also train your model multiple times and choose one when you get max test accuracy.